# #1064 Error Message When trying to export local host database online

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

Hi am an aspiring Computer Scientist. I've been trying to upload my localhost site online for almost a day now. This is what I've done so far:

I created a DB online (from my online hosting acct.), created users and password. I went to my PHPmyAdmin on local host, selected my DB, exported it (a .sql file), edited the URL (find and replace). I went online, to my DB (online) and chose to import DB. I Selected my exported DB file (that of localhost) and clicked Go. I get the following error message:

It tells me:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] `wp_commentmeta` (`meta_id`
>   bigint(20) u' at line 1

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `wp_commentmeta` (

 `meta_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `comment_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `meta_key` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
 `meta_value` LONGTEXT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
PRIMARY KEY (  `meta_id` ) ,
KEY  `comment_id` (  `comment_id` ) ,
KEY  `meta_key` (  `meta_key` ( 191 ) )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT =6;
```

Hope this improves my question?

I really appreciate the work every contributor on this platform has done prior to now. With you guys here at Stack Overflow, I know the nature of my problem, but I've not found a solution that directly applies to it. I can't figure out where the code is not right. Please I need a solution fast, even as people have to register on the site (a WP site) since yesterday. 
Thanks to all.

Comment: remove the brackets in here `[ IF NOT EXISTS ]`. You must've have taken the MySQL example literally from their site and used them. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html those aren't meant to be used, but as an option.

Comment: Thanks @Nana-Partykar, I really appreciate your prompt response. I still get another error:

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) uns' at line 1

Comment: huh??? I'm the one who responded lol

Comment: plus, you tagged as PHP and Wordpress. where are you executing this from? via a script or in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Hey @Fred-ii-, he responded you only. Mistakenly, he saw my name. `:D`

Comment: You should re-write your question with exactly what you're experiencing as an issue. As people respond with help, update your original question underneath with progress. Please don't do it in the comments

Comment: I'm sorry @Fred-ii- , maybe I'm just nervous. People will be stuck now because they can't access that site and register for an event. I've made the changes you suggested, no success yet.

Comment: Are you attempting to run this `CREATE` statement immediately after running another statement, such as creating an earlier table? The error at the `CREATE` keyword suggests this statement is being run after another without a proper `;` delimiter in between.  This statement would work if run in isolation.

Comment: Hi @PrinceElijah, i checked your sql query after removing brackets `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_commentmeta` ...` It worked for me..

Comment: With the exclusion of brackets, it doesn't still work for me @NanaPartykar

Comment: @PrinceElijah You need to post the exact procedure you are using to import your database. Using phpmyadmin's normal import methodology with a properly dumped database, you should encounter no errors.

Comment: What is yr MySQL version? What is your phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: SQL Dump  version 4.1.14
PHP Version: 5.5.12 @fusion3k

Comment: The error message makes it look like there is something (whitespace or a non-visible character) before the 'C' in 'CREATE'.  Try removing anything before that 'C' and see if that helps. (as suggested in the update of Fred's answer)

Comment: @PrinceElijah I've posted an answer below and have made a few edits since it was originally posted. Do (reload) go over it carefully and in its entirety. At this point now, am out of ideas, other than the comments given here by others. I'd like to do more to help, but that is the best to my knowledge.

Comment: **Please note** that [wordpress official](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/02/the-utf8mb4-upgrade/) reports **utf8mb4** update not compatible with **MySQL < 5.5.3**

Answer (score 1):

The only way that you would (still) be receiving that error is because you are very most likely using your code via a PHP script, rather than executing it/inserting those codes inside phpmyadmin.

Since you did tag as PHP, that is the only conclusion I can come up with, since using your code in phpmyadmin, did create it successfully.

Minus the brackets of course, as I stated in comments.

Remove the brackets in here `[ IF NOT EXISTS ]`.

You must've have taken the MySQL example literally from their site and used them.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Those aren't meant to be used, but as an option.

Plus, if executing from a PHP script, it could be a quotes issue and using the wrong ones.

If you are attempting to, or wanting to create the table through a PHP script, an example of this would be:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}
```

However, phpmyadmin does have an "IMPORT" option.

- Open phpMyAdmin by clicking the phpMyAdmin icon
- Select the database in the left menu that you will be working with
- Click Import in the top menu
- Under File to Import, click Browse and select the backup file you previously created (it will be either a .sql .zip or .tar.gz file).
- Click Go at the bottom right

When the database has been imported successfully, you should see a message at the top of the page similar to: Import has been successfully finished, ## queries executed.

- Pulled from http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/phpmyadmin/import-database-using-phpmyadmin

Also consult:

- http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/import-and-export-databases-using-phpmyadmin/

which talks about WordPress.

and

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Restoring_Your_Database_From_Backup

**Another possible reason** could be that there may be some type of unicode (hidden) character that was introduced, and/or a file encoding issue.

TBH; at this point in time, I am out of ideas.

---

**Edit:**

As an option, you can use the following to be run as a PHP script if it's still giving you problems:

Sidenote: This was pre-tested. Replace the `xxx` with your own login credentials.

```
<?php
$DB_HOST = 'xxx';
$DB_USER = 'xxx';
$DB_PASS = 'xxx';
$DB_NAME = 'xxx';

$Link = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($Link->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $Link->connect_error . ']');
}


$sql = "CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
`meta_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`comment_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
`meta_key` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
`meta_value` LONGTEXT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
PRIMARY KEY (  `meta_id` ) ,
KEY  `comment_id` (  `comment_id` ) ,
KEY  `meta_key` (  `meta_key` ( 191 ) )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT = 6
";


if ($Link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $Link->error;
}
```

---

**Important:** Copy this exact code and paste it into the **"SQL"** option in phpmyadmin and **not** "IMPORT".

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `wp_commentmeta` (

`meta_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`comment_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
`meta_key` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
`meta_value` LONGTEXT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
PRIMARY KEY (  `meta_id` ) ,
KEY  `comment_id` (  `comment_id` ) ,
KEY  `meta_key` (  `meta_key` ( 191 ) )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT =6;
```

Then click on "GO". That is how I originally tested your code in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that yr MySQL version is ‘4.1.14’? It's really old.

If it is, the problem is mySQL version.

[**utf8mb4**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) encoding is introduced in MySQL 5.5.3 (released in early 2010).

---

**Also Please note** that [official wordpress docs](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/02/the-utf8mb4-upgrade/) say:

> **The utf8mb4 Upgrade**
>
> In WordPress 4.2, we’re upgrading tables to utf8mb4, when we can. Your site will only upgrade when the following conditions are met:
>
> - You’re currently using the utf8 character set.
> - Your MySQL server is version 5.5.3 or higher (including all 10.x versions of MariaDB).
> - Your MySQL client libraries are version 5.5.3 or higher. If you’re using mysqlnd, 5.0.9 or higher.

Also, in the doc there is en explicit reference to `wp_commentmeta` table.

In our query:

- utf8mb4 charset
- utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation
- wp_commentmeta table
- mySQL 4.1.14

Maybe upgranding mySQL can resolve your problems.

Comment: How can I upgrade MySQL? @fusion3k

Comment: It's not easy task. It's depend of your os and configuration.

Comment: @PrinceElijah Are you sure that vers is 4.1.14? See [this screenshot](http://imgur.com/HFbpaMo) to see how check it

Answer (score 0):

When I contacted my host, they helped me resolve the issue. I got this message:

> I could see that, in the file 'dbxxx.sql', the command 'Use dbxx;' was missing, this is the reason, you were receiving that error when trying to import the SQL file to the database.

My site is now up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when uploading database to server.

Error
SQL query:

```
#
# Table structure of table `wp_commentmeta`
#
CREATE TABLE  `wp_commentmeta` (

 `meta_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `comment_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `meta_key` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
 `meta_value` LONGTEXT COLLATE utf8_unicode_520_ci,
PRIMARY KEY (  `meta_id` ) ,
KEY  `comment_id` (  `comment_id` ) ,
KEY  `meta_key` (  `meta_key` ( 191 ) )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_520_ci;
```

I Just replace all `utf8_unicode_520_ci` with `utf8_unicode_ci` in database. Then I'm able to upload the database. This works for me.
You can try replace all `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` with `utf8_unicode_ci` and `utf8mb4` with utf8 in database. Hope this will works for u.